Next.js 14 App Directory - Next-Translate and Next-Translate Plugin
I found this link: https://focusreactive.com/next-js-redirects/ and I have a project where I am using both app and pages router and using i18n for internalization. I have using both redirects and rewrites and I keep getting 404 or redirected way too many times to get translation to work.
Here is redirect.js
  {
   
    source: '/en/:country/:id/',
    destination: '/en/:country/id',
    locale: false,
    permanent: true,
  }

Then I have rewrites
  {
   
    source: '/en/:country/:id/',
    destination: '/profile/:id',
  }

I keep getting 404 or redirected way too many times.
In my app folder structure I have both: aap-> en->profile and app->profile. None of them work. What am I missing?
@aralroca
